# Python SQL Connector Error

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python, dbconnection

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mysql as mdb
import math
import sys
from decimal import Decimal

conn=mdb.connect('localhost','root','','testdb')
c=conn.cursor()
```

I've saved my script of which the starting lines are given above.

Saved it by the name 'recommend.py'.

Gives the following error while executing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:/Python27/recommend.py", line 8, in <module>
       conn=mdb.connect('localhost','root','','testdb')
       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Comment: Try `MySQLdb` instead of `mysql`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\recommend.py", line 3, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as mdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Getting this error.

Comment: `pip install mysql-python` in the terminal